# allow for zero or more spaces in regex with grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have some files which may look like `mem = 500`, `mem= 100`, `mem =256`, or any combination of `mem`, whitespaces, `=`, and a number. If I assume there is no whitespace I can use:

`grep -oP '(?<=mem=)[0-9]+'`

but how do I change this to allow for white space between `mem` and `=`? Please keep in mind that I *want* to use grep here.

Comment: Not possible. `grep` does not support variable length look-behinds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
grep -oP 'mem\s*=\s*\K[0-9]+' file
```

The **`\K`** simply drops everything matched so far, printing only the number.

This **alternative to a look-behind assertion (such as `(?<=mem=)`)** bypasses the latter's limitation that Tomalak mentions: **look-behind assertions must be *fixed*-length.**

Note: The nonstandard `-P` option - for PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression) support - requires *GNU* `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two `grep` calls like so:

```
grep -oP 'mem *= *[0-9]+' | grep -oP '[0-9]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have GNU grep, you will need Perl, awk, sed etc.

Perl solution:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if m/mem\s*=\s*(\d+)/;'
```

And sed:

```
sed -n 's/.*\mem *= *\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p'
```

awk:

```
awk -F'mem *= *' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: This `awk` will print blank lines if it does not contain `mem`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version:

```
awk -F" *= *" '{print $2}' file
500
100
256
```

If there are other line and you need `mem` only, do:

```
awk -F" *= *" '/mem/{print $2}' file
500
100
256
```